# startMonitoringForRegion works in foreground but not in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, clregion

I am quite new to objective C and region monitoring and I'm working on application that alert you when you enter specific locations. I get my data from JSON.

If the app is running in the foreground (i.e. visible) then the startMonitoringForRegion and NSLog for monitoredRegions is working fine. But when I switch to background mode and try to NSLog monitoredRegions I get:
LOCATIONMANAGER monitored regions1 has 5 results (as it should), LOCATIONMANAGER monitored regions2 has 4 results, LOCATIONMANAGER monitored regions3 has 3 results

```
NSMutableArray *geofences = [NSMutableArray array];


for(NSDictionary *regionDict in jsonTestArray) {
    CLRegion *region = [self mapDictionaryToRegion:regionDict];
    NSLog(@"Region1: %@",region);
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];

    [geofences addObject:region];
}
NSLog(@"jsonTestGeo %@",geofences);

NSLog(@"LOCATIONMANAGER monitored regions1: %@", [self.locationManager monitoredRegions]);
NSLog(@"LOCATIONMANAGER monitored regions2: %@", [self.locationManager monitoredRegions]);
NSLog(@"LOCATIONMANAGER monitored regions3: %@", [self.locationManager monitoredRegions]);
```

Can someone please explain me, what am I missing here...

Comment: Have you enabled the app for background mode to receive location updates?

Comment: I did. I get monitoredregions in background everytime, but not all of them.

Comment: Could you show the code for your `mapDictionaryToRegion` method?

Comment: NSString *title = [dictionary valueForKey:@"description"];
    CLLocationDegrees lat = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees lon =[[dictionary valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
    CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"radius"] doubleValue];
 return  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                              radius:regionRadius
                                          identifier:title];